# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS black screen after The february security update

Tags: 14.04

I decided to install new updates at the end of January. I have made two updates - one upon install and the other one yesterday which was marked as a security update.

After that the system asked for a reboot, and then...black screen. Nothing, absolutely nothing can be done - tried crtl+alt+f(1,2,3,4) to introduce any commands. How do I fix this?

My computer is Asus Eee PC 1215B AMD C-50 1gh, 4gb ram Ati radeon hd 6250, two systems on board.

Comment: When booting your system, can you see the manufacturers logo or something similar? After that shows up, you can try pressing and holding the shift-key to access the grub boot-menu from where you might be able to boot in recovery mode or low-graphics mode

Comment: Do you want help with a problem? 99% of this is a rant and we are not interested in that. It also will lower the amount of people willing to read on.

Comment: Nothing, I forgot to mention I use easy BCD and have two systems on the laptop. After I choose Ubuntu I have nothing, black screen and underscore blinking, totally irresponsive to anything I try to type :(

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind, got carried away that's all. David Foerster, Will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just after the boot process is done, press shift and you will see the "grub" boot menu. In here pick the previous kernel to boot the system so it does not use the newer kernel you installed with the last update. This will get you back into your system.

You also have a 2nd method: when you see the "grub" screen at the bottom are a few options. 1 of them (F6) will get you to edit the boot line. Choose "nomodeset". Example:

[image]

If this boots you can focus on getting the new kernel boot fixed by checking your log files and see if you can find a problem. There probably was a problem with the update for your video card related to this kernel. A purge + install of your video card drive is likely going to fix it for you.

If it does not... stick to the older kernel for now.

Comment: Rinzwind, tried holding/tapping the shift. Doesn't work. I have misinformed you probably cause forgot to say that I used Easy BCD to choose between Win 7 and Ubuntu and have two systems on board. After I choose Ubuntu, got black screen instantly. Tapping or holding shift doesn't work. Tried that :(